# How to shape the data source for PrimeNG Tree (P-Tree) Component?

Tags: primeng

I am very new to the Angular and PrimeNG components.  I want to build a tree view with children nodes, and PrimeNG offered the solution out of the box with the  component.  However, all the examples have hard-coded data sources.  In my case, the data source is from the database, and I don't know if I have to shape my data to match what the P-Tree expected (see below).  If yes, what is the technique for doing it?

Here is an example of the data source for P-Tree.

```
{
            "label": "Pictures",
            "data": "Pictures Folder",
            "expandedIcon": "pi pi-folder-open",
            "collapsedIcon": "pi pi-folder",
            "children": [
                {"label": "barcelona.jpg", "icon": "pi pi-image", "data": "Barcelona Photo"},
                {"label": "logo.jpg", "icon": "pi pi-file", "data": "PrimeFaces Logo"},
                {"label": "primeui.png", "icon": "pi pi-image", "data": "PrimeUI Logo"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is resolved.  A recursive method was used to build a tree hierarchy with the parent ID as root and the children belong the parent.  A data table is passed into the method as the parameter.  The method iterates through the entire data table.

```cs
          foreach (DataRow dr in dtData.Select("ParentID = '" + ID+ "'"))
            {
                // recursive
                folder.children.Add(
                    new ChildFolder()
                    {
                        label = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                        children = GetChildren(Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]), dtData),
                        data = Convert.ToString(dr["ID"])
                    });
            }

            return folder;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me out in this, I am facing similar situation, finding it difficult to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would since the data has to match the TreeNode interface.

```
export interface TreeNode {
    data?: any;
    children?: TreeNode[];
    leaf?: boolean;
    expanded?: boolean;
    label?: string;
    expandedIcon?: string:
    collapsedIcon?: string; 
}
```

If you have an API, you can do something like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class NodeService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getFilesystem() {
        return this.http.get('showcase/resources/data/filesystem.json')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <TreeNode[]> res.json().data);
    }
}
```

The p-treeSelect and p-treeTable docs has a few good examples:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/treeselect https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/treetable.

Comment: My struggling is not knowing how to map my response to the TreeNode type.  Sample response
```json
 "response": [
 {
   "name": Provider - South",
   "id": 6169,
   "parentID": 5954,
   "hasChildren": 1,
   "orgLevel": 2
},
  {
    "name": "Provider 99",
    "id": 6092,
    "parentID": 6169,
    "hasChildren": 0,
    "orgLevel": 3
 },
  {
    "name": "Providers - North",
    "id": 5954,
    "parentID": 1,
    "hasChildren": 1, 
    "orgLevel": 1 },
  {
    "name": "Provider 4",
    "id": 6082,
    "parentID": 5954,
    "hasChildren": 0,
      "orgLevel": 2,
}
```

Comment: @AngularNewbie can you show me what a parent looks like?

Comment: I received some help from an internal colleague for shaping the data to match the PrimeNG P-Tree data source.

Comment: this link my help you @AngularNewbie please if you found more reference about this topic help me